# Maven local repo in a common global directory for multiple parallel execution

Tags: java, maven

I have a machine in which multiple parallel maven execution happen. Each execution executes the below command in a separate workspace directory

`mvn -f main/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests -T 6`

Can someone let me know should I use a separate maven local repo path (`-Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_REPO`) for each execution or I can use a common `.m2` directory for all parallel runs?

- Maven Version 3.5
- Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discsussed in maven [user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/c0dabbcea18f008b443134d3ea2384eff5d6aca7fb9309ef07acd10f@%3Cusers.maven.apache.org%3E) also. Summary of the discussion

> Hello,
>
> It is the other way around, there might be situations where one job
>   relies on the installed artifacts from the other, in this case you
>   would need a shared Repo. It is however bad style. In all other cases
>   you can use a executor- or even workspace-local local repository if
>   you have enough space.
>
> The advantage of avoiding concurrent access is that you get less
>   influences from one job to the other (especially if you work with
>   snapshots or multiple different upstream artifacts with same version
>   in different Repos) and that there is no concurrent downloads (which
>   in itself sometimes leads to checksum errors).
>
> Gruss Bernd